# Querying GPU Devices using Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Is there a way using `windows.h` to query for all GPU Devices installed in the machine? I'm not too sure that this header file is correct for something like this. But I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use NVML or CUDA, rather something more native than depending on other libraries.

All that I need to query is how many GPU's there are in the system and potentially some information surrounding it.

Once I've done this, I'm hoping to be able to do the same for the CPU.

Any push in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, what info do you need about the GPUs?

Comment: 1. How many GPU's are available?
2. Are they NVIDIA or AMD?
3. Model (not essential)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something general - it's the Vulkan API.

Functions like `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices`, `vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties` and `vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures`.

The `VkPhysicalDeviceProperties` from `vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties`gives the `vendorID` (0x10DE for NVIDIA, 0x1002 for AMD).

Comment: Is the Vulkan API available in Qt 5.9? Or would I need to upgrade to 5.10?

Comment: It's not related to Qt. Vulkan comes with the graphics drivers (as `vulkan-1.dll` on windows, `libvulkan.so` on Linux). You can open it dynamically with dlopen and get necessary functions (or use some third-party dynamic loaders or static runtimes to do the same).